# Unity systemWidth and systemHeight not changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, winapi, resolution

i want change display resolution 1920X1080 to 1080X1920

so i used ChangeDisplaySettingsEx and Display changed successfully

but display.systemWidth and display.systemHeight not changed

How can I changed systemWidth and systemHeight

Here is Code:

```
        uint deviceID = 1;

        DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
        d.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(d);

        NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, deviceID, ref d, 0);

        if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(d.DeviceName, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
        {

            defaultWidth = dm.dmPelsWidth;
            defaultHeight = dm.dmPelsHeight;

            if (!(dm.dmDisplayOrientation == NativeMethods.DMDO_90))
            {
                dm.dmPelsHeight = defaultWidth;
                dm.dmPelsWidth = defaultHeight;
                dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_90;

                DISP_CHANGE iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                d.DeviceName, ref dm, IntPtr.Zero,
                DisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(Display.displays[1].systemWidth + " " + Display.displays[1].systemHeight);
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(Display.displays[1].renderingWidth + " " + Display.displays[1].renderingHeight);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [`Screen.SetResolution`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) was no option?

Comment: I understand that this option only applies to the first screen. And the resolution of the second screen will be different from the first. ex.) dp1 is 1920x1080, dp2 is 1080x1920